# Creating React apps using npx create-react-app is very slow , Is there any way to speed it up?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, create-react-app, npx

I am a new Developer trying to Learn React , so in this process I am creating multiple react projects
So I have created react projects using npx create-react-app , so every time I create react app , it takes a long
time create it , is there any way , to speed up the creation of react app using npx create-react-app,
as I am creating lot of different apps for learning purposes

Comment: copy and paste the react folder you've created once maybe?

Comment: nice idea , not thought of it thank you

Answer (score 1):

Issue is reported [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9886) and added to next [milestone](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/milestone/78).

If you want temporary patch you can follow this [comment](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9886#issuecomment-718254173)

1. Install patch-package https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package#set-up
2. Open the webpack file: `node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js`
3. Add cache to the eslint plugin

```
new​ ​ESLintPlugin​(​{​
  ​cache​: ​true​,​
  ...
})
```

4. Run the patch package script `yarn patch-package react-scripts`
5. Normally run the app now.

Remove the patch later after fix.